# Justify Text in a column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

how can I justify the text in a column in a `longtable`? I have a table like this but I do not know how to justify the text or set the text to adjust to the column width

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{longtable} %Long tables
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[H]{|c|c|l|c|l|c|c|}
\hline
    &&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Staff poorly or\\not trained in\\the 
    archiving of the\\reports\end{tabular}&3&\begin{tabular}[c]
   {@{}l@{}}Implementation of training programs at the\\start of the trial, during the trial\\and when new staff members are recruited\\and define clearly in a written document\\the require skills and experience\\to be part of the trial staff.\\The requirements should be defined by\\a member of the staff with enough\\experience. Monitorise through audit\\its accomplishment\end{tabular}&1&9\\
    \hline
   \end{longtable}
   \end{landscape}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `p{<width>}` column type to get text justified within that `<width>`. If you need also vertical centering use `m{<width>}` (requires `array` package). Finally to prevent ugly word hyphenations (as a result of justification), precede the `m` columns with `>{\raggedright}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{longtable} %Long tables
\usepackage{pdflscape,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|>{\raggedright}m{4cm}|c|>{\raggedright}m{7cm}|c|c|}
\hline
 & & Staff poorly or not trained in the archiving of the reports & 3 & 
 Implementation of training programs at the start of the trial, during the trial and when new staff members are recruited and define clearly in a written document the require skills and experience to be part of the trial staff. The requirements should be defined by a member of the staff with enough experience. Monitorise through audit its accomplishment & 1 & 9 \\
 \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! that really helped me, I have the text to adjust to the width but is not aligned on the right, just on the left. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @user141098 - Yes, `>{\raggedright}` is responsible for this, if you don't like the left-alignment, just remove these two `>{\raggedright}` before `m{..}`.